# Result set in Oracle with Union

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle11g

I have made union with two query in Oracle SQL

```
SELECT account_number, SUM(amount_settled)    
  FROM table W
 WHERE account_number= &acc
   AND Component = 'PROFIT_1'
 GROUP BY account_number
 UNION 
SELECT account_number, SUM(amount)  
  FROM table S
 WHERE account_number=  &acc
   AND amount_tag= 'PROFIT_2' 
 GROUP BY account_number 
 ORDER BY account_number
```

I am  getting  value in result  set as one  below  the other

```
SUM(AMOUNT_SETTLED)
1   36260.16
2   36342.16
```

I want  to  display in single row on beside the other

```
SUM(AMOUNT_SETTLED)       SUM(E.AMOUNT)
36260.16                  36342.16
```

how to achieve  this with two Different Table in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is your current case ( *without the lines those contain substitution variables* ) :

```
SELECT account_number, SUM(amount_settled)    
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE component = 'PROFIT_1'
 GROUP BY account_number
 UNION 
SELECT account_number, SUM(amount)  
  FROM table2 t2
 WHERE amount_tag= 'PROFIT_2' 
 GROUP BY account_number
```

and you might need to use `CROSS JOIN` among the subqueries derived individually from each tables through use of conditional aggregation :

```
SELECT sum_amount_settled, sum_amount
  FROM ( SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN component = 'PROFIT_1' THEN amount_settled END) AS sum_amount_settled   
           FROM table1) 
 CROSS JOIN ( SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN amount_tag = 'PROFIT_2' THEN amount END) AS sum_amount  
                FROM table2)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=5ae7b5faf6b7e5822978e9633bdc7a23)</kbd>